# corrupted winload.efi in a windows 10 copy

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, repair

I have got a mini computer with 32Gb of internal storage. Windows 10 takes at least 20Gb and the disk is now full.

So I decided to move the system to an external HDD SSD drive, using minitool partition wizard.

After the cloning, I have got this configuration:

[image]

disk 1 is the internal disk.
You can see 2 EFI partitions in the 2 disks(I don't know if it is important but maybe there should be only one).

When I try to start my computer, I am asked to choose which windows to launch.
If I choose the first, the OS starts fine(but I have no more enough space).
If I choose the second, I have a blue screen and a message :

> error 0xc000000e one required file is missing of contains errors.
>   \Windows\system32\winload.efi

thanks to google, I learnt the it means an important boot failure, and saw some ways of fixing that; one way is :

- enter in the terminal via a windows distribution disk
- bootrec /ScanOs
- bootrec /RebuildBcd
- bootrec /FixMbr
- bootrec /FixBoot

but then I have an arror after "bootrec /RebuildBcd" : if lists one disk, I get a question ("add installation to boot list?"), and then I get the error "the system cannot find the file specified".

My questions are:

- maybe a good tool to copy/move a windows 10 system could avoid me too long fixes
- if not, is the problem linked to two EFI? if so, can I remove one?

Comment: You cloned your drive incorrectly.  You are better off starting over and making an exact clone, then extending the system partition, after the fact.  You can delete the recovery partition, then restore that one partition, after the fact (or don't since it's not required for Windows to boot)

Comment: hello, I tried this but the result is the same. In the picture above, there are some extra partitions because I added linux, thinking it could add some working boot menu, but this was a failure also.